# JVM Crash sporadically

Tags: java, jvm

we are facing an issue were our application JVM suddenly crash. An excerpt is as follows.

```
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 #
 #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002aaaab11e00c, pid=27138, tid=1570617664
 #
 # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 # Problematic frame:
 # C  [libzip.so+0x1000c]*** glibc detected *** /xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java: malloc(): memory corruption (fast):
0x000000001a0ca730 ***

[thread 1595881792 also had an error]
[thread 1545353536 also had an error]
[thread 1628514624 also had an error]
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3991e72648]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x7d)[0x3991e72efd]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so[0x2b23b31ce5e9]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so[0x2b23b2e5810c]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so[0x2b23b2e582b5]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so[0x2b23b31d3cf9]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so[0x2b23b2edb7ef]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so[0x2b23b3353542]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so[0x2b23b3354b04]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so(JVM_handle_linux_signal+0x14f)[0x2b23b31daadf]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3992a0de80]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so[0x2aaaab11e00c]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so[0x2aaaab11eb37]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so[0x2aaaab116b90]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so[0x2aaaab115433]
/xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so(Java_java_util_zip_Deflater_deflateBytes+0x269)[0x2aaaab111049]
[0x2aaaac5a9244]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:21 14272741                           /xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 00:21 14272741                           /xncpkgs/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
```

The application runs on CentOS 5.2, and Tomcat 6.0.35.

Any help in understanding these errors would be much appreciated.

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have googled for "Java_java_util_zip_Deflater_deflateBytes+0x269" as the most salient part from your report, and this is where it took me:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028216

It says that it is a known bug, reported against Java 7 Update 45.

Comment: Thanks Marko! the link is most useful.

Answer (score -1):

**Smells like a hardware problem. Have you tried running any diagnostics?**

Comment: We didn't explicitly run any diagnostics, primarily because the servers on which the applications were running on have slightly different configurations in terms of memory.